# How to get rid of the "Flash Player Auto Update Daemon” popup?

Tags: mojave, software-update, adobe-flash, 32-bit

Since the launch of Catalina I've been getting this popup about "Flash Player Auto Update Daemon" that I cannot figure out how to get rid of, even though I'm still using Mojave.

[image: annoying Updater popup]

I know it's a 32-bit app but I can't find it in the Applications folder. I checked the Legacy Software list, I see the suspect: **fpsaud**.

I found its folder `/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Flash Player Install Manager`. Can I simply delete this or is anything going to break? Is there another way to get rid of this popup?

Comment: [This ite](https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/14784-flash-player-auto-update-daemon-pop-up-scam-mac) says it's caused by malware. Have you tried running Malwarebytes?

Comment: These days I wouldn't have Flash anywhere in the building - whether that particular "updater" is from adobe or not, many cams have been pushed through fakes. Get rid of Flash altogether, run a malware scanner [if not two] over the machine to make sure whether that one belongs to Adobe or not.

Comment: @fsb Malwarebytes says my mac is clean

Comment: @Tetsujin honestly I can't remember the last time I used flash for anything, but since I have Animator CC installed I wasn't sure if this was something I could just get rid of  or not.

Comment: I'd have thought CC19 & 20 would be completely 64-bit ready; I can't recall anything Adobe complaining about 64-bit in quite some time. I'd say safest would be to uninstall Flash completely, then if Animator thinks it still needs it, it will be easy enough to put back from a known official source.

Comment: Look for `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.adobe.fpsaud.plist` in your main (not Home) library.  Delete it, restart, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what I found and @fsb comment, I deleted the folder `/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Flash Player Install Manager` with all contents and `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.adobe.fpsaud.plist`, no more Flash update popups!

Comment: Glad it helped fix the problem!